# Why is "blank" is missing in django.forms.CharField, but present in django.db.models.CharField?

Tags: python, django, forms, models, django-1.5

## Background

I have a model with two fields that are set the blank:

```
class News(models.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                           
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True)                                                                                                                                                         
    info = models.TextField(blank = True)
```

The thing is that I want to set the `max_length` dynamically when the form is built, so I have a custom form:

```
class NewsForm(forms.ModelForm):                                                                                                                                                                                    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                                            
        super(NewsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                             

        title_max_length = 20                                                                                                                                                                                       
        info_max_length = 100                                                                                                                                                                                       

        self.fields["title"] = forms.CharField(max_length = title_max_length)                                                                                                                                       
        self.fields["info"] = forms.CharField(                                                                                                                                                                      
            widget = forms.Textarea,                                                                                                                                                                                
            validators = [                                                                                                                                                                                          
                MaxLengthValidator(info_max_length)                                                                                                                                                                 
            ]                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        )
```

**Note: Those two length values are actually fetched from the database, but I chose not to include that code to keep the examples shorter.**

## The problem

When I'm using those custom fields the `blank` option is overwritten/ignored.

I tried just adding the max_length, widget and validators to the existing fields, like this:

```
class NewsForm(forms.ModelForm):                                                                                                                                                                                    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                                            
        super(NewsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                             

        title_max_length = 20                                                                                                                                                                                       
        info_max_length = 100                                                                                                                                                                                       

        self.fields["title"].max_length = title_max_length                                                                                                                                                          
        self.fields["info"].widget = forms.Textarea                                                                                                                                                                 
        self.fields["info"].validators = [MaxLengthValidator(info_max_length)]
```

When doing this the `blank` option works, but the dynamic max_length is not applied to the form.

I tried to look in the django source, but I'm quite new so it's too much to take in right now.

**Is there some way I can achieve this?**

Comment: Did you try adding the required=False parameter to your form?

Comment: @AlagappanRamu: No, I did not. I was so focused on looking for "blank" that I most have missed it in the docs. I added `required = False` in the `CharField` creation and that solved the problem. Write your comment as an answer so I can accept it and upvote it. Thank you!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When creating your form, add the following parameter to `CharField` apart from the `max_length`, widget and validators:

```
forms.CharField(...,required = False)
```

In Django, `blank=True` in models correlates to `required=False` in forms.

Comment: <del>not working for me in Django 1.11, still asks in django admin</del> Works after server restart (hmm, it usually auto-reloads)